# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation with negative M_PI

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios8, cgaffinetransform

I'm using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` to rotate a `UIView` inside an animation block, and I want to rotate it counterclockwise for `180º`.

However when I put

```
myView.animateWithDuration(0.5)
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI))
```

it still rotates clockwise. What's confusing me is that if I write "manually" the value of `M_PI`, it works as expected

```
 // this will rotate counterclockwise
 myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-3.14159265358979))
```

Why this behavior?

Edit: added I'm using an animation block

Comment: i cannot reproduce your issue in objective-c or swift, always rotates clockwise - rotating by -3.141592 gives the desired effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I stated in my first comment and as Segii already wrote: the animation will take the shortest distance between where it's value is at now and where it is trying to go. The best solution imho is to use `CABasicAnimation` for forcing a counterclockwise rotation:

```
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
anim.fromValue = M_PI
anim.toValue = 0
anim.additive = true
anim.duration = 2.0

myView.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "rotate")
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI))
```

This will rotate it by 180 counter clockwise in one go.

The angle you specify in the last line + the `fromValue` is the starting angle -> 0. And then the rotation will go the distance `(toValue - fromValue) = 0 - M_PI = - M_PI` -> counter clockwise 180 degree rotation.

Comment: this doesn't work for me for some reason.
also I'm using `CGFloat.pi` as this preferred with swift 3.0

Comment: M_PI and -M_PI didn't work for me, however subtracting/adding 0.01 from/to the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation values can create that shortest distance for the animation to take, but visually you won't see a difference.

Answer (score 5):

As I understood, you're trying to rotate view within animation block. `animateWithDuration` will always perform animation with the shortest way. So, M_PI and -M_PI gives the same destination position. The reason, why you get expected animation direction when setting it manually is that your manual value is really  smaller that M_PI, so the shortest way to rotate is counterclockwise.

To get expected behaviour, you'll have to chain at least two animations, 
splitting you rotation angle. For example

```
//first animation block
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI/2))CGAffineTransformMakeRotation;
//second animation block
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI/2))CGAffineTransformMakeRotation;
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI/2))
```

Or, much more reliable, use CAKeyframeAnimation